# Does the hydrogen ion actually exist?

Tags: bond, ions, hydrogen

A chemistry test I did was an IGCSE test. One of the questions was

> Is Hydrogen Chloride ionic or covalent?

Now, on a sheet I have been given, it states the hydrogen ion is $\ce{H+}$. So, it forms a positive ion, like metals. I'm fine with that. I know that hydrogen is strange and I also know that the (I)GCSE chemistry curriculum simplifies/lies a lot. The bonding in Hydrogen Chloride is covalent. Now, since a 'Hydrogen ion' is just a proton, I wanted to know whether in reality it actually exists or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes free $\ce{H+}$ ions, protons, really exist.

Protons are constantly emanating from the sun and reaching Earth.

The proton flux is continuously [monitored by satellite](http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/products/goes-proton-flux).

However, in a solution such as water, instead of bare $\ce{H+}$ ions, they are $\ce{H3O+}$ or larger ions such as $\ce{H5O2+}$ or $\ce{H9O4+}$.

When $\ce{HCl}$ dissolves, the proton is transferred to a water molecule to form $\ce{H3O+}$.

$\ce{HCl}$ only has 17% ionic character according to Pauling's *The Nature of the Chemical Bond*, so it is covalent, but reacts with water to form separate ions in solution.

For more information see [Eigen or Zundel Ion: News from Calculated and
Experimental Photoelectron Spectroscopy](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cphc.200600476/pdf):

> The appearance
>   of the hydronium ion was and is
>   currently debated as several possible
>   structures, three of them being $\ce{H3O+}$
>   (the Eigen cation), $\ce{H5O2+}$ (the Zundel
>   cation) and $\ce{H9O4+}$ (the strongly solvated
>   Eigen cation)

and

[Both Zundel and Eigen Isomers Contribute to the IR Spectrum of the Gas-Phase $\ce{H9O4+}$ Cluster](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp410446d):

> The “Eigen cation”, $\ce{H3O+(H2O)3}$, is the most prevalent protonated water structure in the liquid phase

Comment: Wouldn't $\ce{HCl}$ dissociation also yield $\ce{H9O4+}$ and not only  $\ce{H3O+}$?

Comment: @mannaia yes, see here for details : http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/hydrogen_ions.html