# Can a substance donate a proton without the proton getting accepted by another substance?

Tags: acid-base

I have read that the concept of Brønsted and Lowry is based on the fact that acid-base reactions involve the transfer of $\ce{H+}$ ions from one substance *to another*, and that an acid is a substance that donates a proton *to another substance*, but:

can a substance donate a proton without the proton getting accepted by another substance? So for example:
$$\ce{AH -> A- + H+}$$
without reacting with another substance?

If yes: Is this a Brønsted-Lowry acid?

Comment: The process itself should be possible depending on the nature of A. Kind of photolysis. But in absence of media it will go reverse.  Nothing in common conditions....

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/46882/do-bare-protons-exist-even-transiently-in-aqueous-solution https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41997/does-the-hydrogen-ion-actually-exist

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I can find to this involves a most unlikely proton donor.  Given an appropriate base, [sodium hydride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_hydride) donates a proton for encapsulation in the base (rather than forming a localised covalent bond), leaving the valence electrons on sodium (!) in **inverse sodium hydride**.  The proton is not free (a completely free proton is possible only in plasma), but analogous to complexed metal ion or solvated electron.

Comment: "Encapsulation in the base"? Does it mean that the base receives/accepts the proton?

Comment: Yes, some bonding interaction (in this case between the protons and lone pairs on nitrogen atoms in the base) to drive the "reversed" oxidation states.  But you avoid the usual localized covalent bonding, the encapsulated species may be fairly called ironically bonded $\ce{H^+}$.

Comment: I don’t think this qualifies as the proton not getting accepted by anything since it does get accepted by the encapsulation host.

Comment: Hence, "the closest thing I can find".

Comment: It's not closest by any means and no idea why you put such example. BTW it would be good to use links instead of bare urls.

Comment: @Mithoron I am curious about your ideas.  Superacids still involve a localized covalent bond to the reactive hydrogen and I was looking for an interaction that does not reduce to such a bond.

Comment: I actually have a few, and this wasn't so dupey... There are things even more powerful then typical superacids.